# Will a Outlook 2007 client show MailTips using Exchange 2010?

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2007

I am looking at enabling the MailTips in Exchange 2010 but was curious to know whether they will show in the Outlook 2007 client? I am specifically interested in the "The following recipient is outside the organization" message being displayed!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like I have found my answer:

**Q: What clients does MailTips support?** 
A: Though the screenshots posted above are from Outlook Web App (known as Outlook Web Access in previous versions), MailTips are also a feature of Outlook 2010. Legacy Outlook/OWA versions are not supported.

From: http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2009/04/28/introducing-mailtips.aspx